# What is my eyesight

Tags: optometry, glasses, ratio, myopia-nearsightedness

According to my glasses prescription, both of my eyes are (or need) -1.00. I know I'm nearsighted, and it's a low number so it's not too bad. I'm trying to find what this would be as far as 20 out of what number